# How to prevent people from using VPN's to bypass an IP-ban?

Tags: windows, registry, game-development

I am a game developer and I am working on a banning system for my multiplayer game. The method I am trying to implement is an IP-ban. But I have encountered an issue, I know that players can use a VPN to bypass an IP-ban.

I was thinking of maybe creating some sort of a "tag" into the system, for example a hidden file or a registry value. This might be unsecure and there is no guarantee that someone doesn't find this "tag".

I don't know if my approach to this problem was good, if it wasn't then I would like to know how this could be done better. If my approach was good, then how could I hide such a "tag" really deep and securely into the system?

Comment: You can have the client send all of the local IP addresses to the server for evaluation. Of course, that can be attacked, too. Better is to ban the entire account.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ultimate system to secure a banned player will stay banned. If that individual has the time and money he will always find a way to come back. So just keep this in mind when coding the ban system.

IP bans are very common and they can indeed be avoided by something as simple as using a VPN or Proxy service.
You might try to overcome those by monitoring most used VPN's exit IPs and creating a blacklist with those IPs. But I'd argue is not a very good solution since it might affect people who are trying to play your videogame without cheating too thus creating "false positives". Also it is very hard to keep track of all the VPN's IPs.

One way to deal with it might be to implement a hardware ban which will effectively use the MAC address to ban a user.
This system can also be bypassed since changing MAC address is possible by spoofing it.

I'd suggest you to implement an IP ban if your game is still under development as it will be enough for a while. Then try to implement a hardware ban.

If you feel like it's still not enough, you might want to add some sort of alert system that tracks each player's score/activity in game and compares it with what you consider is normal without cheats.
This way you as a dev will get warnings each times there is a player who might be cheating and you can manually decide if it's worth a ban or not.